# How to copy the data of FILTERED data from one sheet to another with same format

Tags: vba

I have the similar question as in the link

[Copy a rows contents and formatting (to another sheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153853/copy-a-rows-contents-and-formatting-to-another-sheet)

I'm trying to copy the data from one sheet to another sheet in the same workbook with the below code and I'm able to copy, but the format of the cells are getting changed after copying, How can I copy the data with the same cell formats (with same length, width , color etc)

```
With ActiveSheet
     .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(NewSheet).Select
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
    , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
```